# Jelly validateButton can't access Java method

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I'm trying to write a simple Jenkins plugin.
I'm facing problem with Jelly validateButton however; it can't access Java method.

Since I'm not quite familiar with Jelly and Java, I've been using this Wiki as a reference point - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jelly+form+controls

Here is what I get in Jenkins:

```
ERROR
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /tagBuild. Reason:

    Not Found

Powered by Jetty://
```

Here is my Jelly code:

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:f="lib/form" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson">
    <l:layout norefresh="true">
        <st:include page="sidepanel.jelly" it="${it.build}"/>
        <l:main-panel>
            <f:form method="post">
                <f:entry title="${%Milestone Name}" help="Enter Milestone name to tag with...">
                    <f:textbox field="milestoneName" />
                </f:entry>
                <f:validateButton title="${%Tag Build}" progress="${%Tagging...}" method="tagBuild" with="milestoneName" />
            </f:form>
        </l:main-panel>
    </l:layout>
</j:jelly>
```

And here is the Java class:

```
import hudson.model.AbstractBuild;
import hudson.model.Action;
import hudson.util.FormValidation;
import org.kohsuke.stapler.QueryParameter;

public class MilestoneLabelingPlugin implements Action {
    AbstractBuild build;
    public AbstractBuild getBuild() { return this.build; }
    public MilestoneLabelingPlugin(AbstractBuild build) {
        super();
        this.build = build;
    }
    public String getUrlName() { return "MilestoneLabelingPlugin"; }
    public String getDisplayName() { return "Label Milestone Build"; }
    public String getIconFileName() { return "/plugin/milestone-labeling-plugin/icon/labelMilestoneBuild.png"; }

    public FormValidation doTagBuild(@QueryParameter("milestoneName") final String milestoneName) {
        return FormValidation.ok("Success!!" + milestoneName);
    }

}
```

The most interesting part is that I've tried to use Submit button, with  configured to run a method and it worked. Only problem was that I wasn't able to read value from input field :/

Is there anyone who had similar problem? Or someone who can tell me what am I doing wrong.

Thanks for all replies in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is as explained in the [Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jelly+form+controls) : "This method needs to be on the Descriptor class that owns this form fragment."  Looks like FormValidation method is only supported for Describable classes.

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit confused. According to this wiki (https://github.com/jenkinsci/pretested-integration-plugin/wiki/Jelly-configuration-information), Descriptor class is the class in which You implement getDisplayName() method. Also most Wikis describing interaction between Java and Jelly say, that Jelly finds the correct Java class, to call method from, based upon name of package containg particular .jelly file.

Comment: That's right, but some classes implement the Describable interface storing their metadata in the Descriptor object as explained in Descriptor class documentation: http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/?hudson/model/Descriptor.html . Actions are not Describable, so it looks like you can't put FormValidation on them. I'll verify this later, don't have the time right now.

Comment: Hi, could You please suggest which interface should I implement? The thing is, that I need my plugin to be available on build level only (after clicking on particular build). To achieve this, I found out that the only ExtensionPoint I can use is TransientActionFactory<AbstractItem>. It seems to require implementing Action... So I'm kind of stuck... Maybe You know some other ExtensionPoint I could use...